# Tableau Publish report Error

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api

We have Tableau Desktop & Redshift as datasource. When we are publishing the report to Tableau server (hosted) we are getting following error :

An unexpected error occurred on the server. If you continue to receive this error please contact your Tableau Server Administrator.

TableauException: Could not connect to the server; A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [58.89.281.166:5439] Unable to connect to the server "abc.redshift.amazonaws.com". Check that the server is running and that you have access privile... 
2014-06-17 13:56:20.974 (U6BI2gq@AWoAAB0gowQAAAGi,0,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely caused by the Tableau Server not being able to access the Redshift Server you listed. It looks like a time out occurred which indicates that a connection attempt failed.

Since it's hosted, you might not be able to verify the connection directly. If you can log onto the Tableau Server and access Windows, you can attempt to establish a connection to the RedShift server at the command line using a tool like Telnet. You need to make sure that the Tableau Server in question can access the Redshift server (verify firewall and security settings for both the Tableau Server and Redshift instance).

Comment: It was issue with security group